# how do I calculate a weighted psnr?

Tags: matlab

I need to produce a weighted PSNR, for this, I use the following code, but the MSE is not true. could you please tell me what should I do for this?

```
mse_IQA_GN_ns=sum(sum(((ref(:)-GN_ns(:)).^2).*IQA_map(:)))/numel(ref);
psnr_IQA_GN_ns=10*log10(255^2/mse_IQA_GN_ns)
```

the `ref` is the original image and `GN_ns` is the attacked image. `IQA_map` is the weight map. I do not know how can I calculate MSE with this weight. what is the problem of the above code?all images have size `512x512`.
when I use the following code for MSE the output is different from `immse` in Matlab!! 
when I use the above code for calculating the mse for Lena before and after manipulation, the MSE using `immse` is `1.7100e+03`but using the below mse function is 0.048. why does it happen? calculating mse using the following code is wrong?
Thank you.

```
mse=sum(sum(((ref(:)-GN_ns(:)).^2)))/numel(ref);
```

Comment: Why do you have two calls to `sum` in the mse calculation? Probably doesn't make any difference, but if nothing else confusing.
Regardless, you should show what is different or wrong, not just say "the output is different". Why not make a toy example with a few values that we can actually run ourselves? It may help you debug yourself! See [ask] and [mre].

Comment: when I use the above code for calculating the mse for Lena before and after manipulation, the MSE using `immse` is `1.7100e+03`but using the below mse function is 0.048. why does it happen?

Comment: also, the type of my images are uint8, can be the problem for this?